# How do I link a dynamic library with qmake into my app?

Tags: qmake

In my qmake .pro file I add my desired dynamic library to LIB which allows for compilation but doesn't link to the library in the compiled application (i.e. I get a library not found error at run time).

The problem is that I have the library in my build directory, not in the system directory (i.e. /usr/lib). But, I want to generate a OSX app that doesn't touch the system outside of the .app folder.

Also, I'd link to know how to do this on a linux system - is it possible?

My question is related to the [Qmake generating a proper .app question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904/getting-qmake-to-generate-a-proper-app) but differs in that the link that answers that question doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a wrapper script round your program so the current working directory is in the dynamic library search path:

```
#!/bin/bash
export  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.
./program
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using LD_LIBRARY_PATH but it looks like the best option for now. Thanks!

Comment: How would I tell qmake to wrap the application with the script? Or, is the best bet to add the script by hand (which is kind of annoying)?

Comment: You would have to add it by hand.